# An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (7854D9A9) Google Play console

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I am trying to upload a new APK and I get An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (7854D9A9)
and I can see the APK uploaded and attached but when I refresh the page it is no more there[image]

Comment: just ignore the message, and continue to rollout.

Answer (score 6):

Google Play Console is just having some issues right now, both new and old versions are not functional.

We'll just have to wait, I'm sure their support team is already aware of this.

Comment: I tried to upload the app icon, I also got the same error. As well as can't change so many fields in the play console.

Comment: How did it got resolved then?

Answer (score 3):

The Play Console seems broken.
General uploading to the Console currently doesn't work not just APK.
I just tried uploading screenshots and featured graphics and same error occurred.

Also trying to access the old console currently gives a **403** error.

It's 12 days already, It ought to have been fixed but it isn't.